# About ISP giving a Public Dynamic IP

Tags: networking, isp

The ISP gives a public IP address to its customer, and it uses DHCP to do that.
Now the thing is, are they still using a nat public IP address?

My own understanding would be: private IP - nat - my public dynamic IP - nat - isp public IP - isp servers - destination.

Typical nat would be: private IP - nat - public IP - internet.

I can do port forward, so I guess I am not natted. But the results in traceroute got me confused.

Outbound from core1.mnl1.he.net and Inbound to my IP. Traceroute to my IP from core1.mnl1.he.net:

[image]

Outbound from my IP and Inbound to core1.mnl1.he.net. Traceroute to core1.mnl1.he.net from my IP:

[image]

Now my second hop, why does it shows 49.149.x.1? that .1 must be the gateway of the isp router, and from my own understanding, it should show 49.149.x.125
It did show though on outbound traceroute from the core1.mnl1.he.net, and the .1 disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now the thing is are they still using a nat public ip address?

Probably not. There is practically no reason to use NAT between two public address ranges.

If you were behind Carrier-Grade NAT, it is *technically* possible that the ISP would use public addresses for the NATed customers... but doing so would **completely defeat the point of CGNAT** – which is to avoid giving a public address to every customer.

Instead, customers behind a CGNAT would usually receive addresses either from the special private range 100.64.0.0/10 (reserved for this purpose), or from one of the usual private ranges (such as 10.0.0.0/8).

NAT does not imply dynamic address assignment.
Dynamic address assignment does not imply NAT.

> But the results in traceroute got me confused

Hops in 'traceroute' are not the addresses themselves – they are *routers*. Any router will usually have multiple addresses but is still just one hop. (Packets don't travel from address to address, but from host to router to host.)

For example, your home router has two interfaces, with an IP address on each of them (192.168.1.1 on the 'LAN' interface and 49.149.x.125 on 'WAN'). However, the whole router counts as a single "hop" and will generate only one response to a traceroute.

Usually, the router will respond from an address that belongs to the same interface that the original packet arrived from. So if you started the trace from 'LAN' side, the router will respond as 192.168.1.1 – but the trace packets were received through 'WAN', the same router will look to be 49.149.x.125.

```
           [...]
             ↕
  ┌─────── ??? ──────────┐
  │  your ISP's gateway  │
  └──── 49.149.x.1 ──────┘
             ↕
  ┌─ WAN = 49.149.x.125 ─┐
  │    your own router   │
  └─ LAN = 192.168.1.1 ──┘
             ↕
         [your PC]
```

The same applies to the majority of all routers seen in traceroute. If you run traces in opposite directions, you'll mostly see different IP addresses, but a lot of the time they'll come from exactly the same routers – just the opposite-facing network connection.

For example, on the HE.NET side you have:

```
     [core1.mnl1.he.net]
             ↕    
┌ 10ge7-4 = 184.104.192.101 ─┐
│      core1.hkg1.he.net     │              (The "core" routers have many
└ 100ge10-1 = 184.105.64.129 ┘               more interfaces, but this
             ↕                               specific path only uses two.)
┌─ 100ge10-2 = 184.105.64.130 ┐
│      core1.tyo1.he.net      │
└ 100ge11-2 = 184.105.213.118 ┘
             ↕
           [...]
```

So when you start a traceroute *to* core1.mnl1, the routers reply using addresses facing you (.213.118 and .64.129). And when core1.mnl1 starts a trace, it sees addresses facing mnl1 (.192.101 and .64.130) from the same routers.

Comment: Nice answer, may I add two suggestions: it should be "Traceroute doesn't show **interfaces**" not "Traceroute doesn't show **addresses**" (because Traceroute does show addresses, the addresses of the routers). Also I would switch between terminology, either use "router" or "gateway" (or explain the connection between the two), I think otherwise it might be confusing for some users.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is the best one I could find. Regarding in this I have question the line "Usually, the router will respond from an address that belongs to the same interface that the original packet arrived from. So, if you started the trace from 'LAN' side, the router will respond as 192.168.1.1 – but the trace packets were received through 'WAN', the same router will look to be 49.149.x.125."